# How can I build Docker image via anaconda

Tags: django, dockerfile, anaconda

I want to build django project use Docker

the following libraries are required

- Django
- Pillow
- opencv-python
- scipy
- numpy
- django-mdeditor
- markdown
- django-markdownx
- mysqlclient

Instead of running with Pip command, I want to run with anaconda but I still haven't figured out how to run it.

please help me, thank you!!!

Comment: Just use [`anaconda`](https://hub.docker.com/r/continuumio/anaconda3) Docker image and `conda install library_name` commands to install libraries with `anaconda` instead of `pip`